# NodeJS Zlib support for LZW ("compress") algorithm?

Tags: node.js, compression, zlib, lzw

I've got a Node/ExpressJS server whose client software only has access to the "compress" (LZW) algorithm for de/compression.

As far as I can tell the Node 12.X [zlib library](https://nodejs.org/api/zlib.html) does *not* support LZW. There also don't appear to be any modules in npm that handle LZW in a fast, general way on content larger than a few hundred bytes.

Does anyone know of a way to efficiently and, ideally, natively use LZW on a Node server? Is something in Zlib compatible with LZW? My use case is for data up to a few tens of kilobytes.

Everything is in Docker, so I could install `ncompress` on the host and use `child_process` to call it directly, or something, but that seems convoluted.

Comment: have you checked out npm, there is quite a few I found with 1 search

Comment: I have, but they all have tiny numbers of downloads and are generally just for strings or other specific use cases.

Comment: [this one?](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lzwcompress)

Comment: @DanStarns it looks like that one is doing a bunch of non-standard stuff. It may use LZW behind the scenes, but it's adding a layer of functionality that wouldn't be compatible with a straight LZW implementation since it's basically meant to de/hydrate javascript objects.

Comment: I see, give a shout if you find anything that works or if you implement it yourself

Comment: @DanStarns turns out the compression method the client uses is actually "deflate", which is great since Node's zlib supports that. I'll leave the question up since the answer may still be useful to someone, if there ever is an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this without any external library.
These are two LZW encode and decode functions.

> function en(c) {   var x = "charCodeAt", b, e = {}, f = c.split(""), d
> = [], a = f[0], g = 256;   for (b = 1; b < f.length; b++) c = f[b], null != e[a + c] ? a += c :(d.push(1 < a.length ? e[a] :ax),
> e[a + c] = g, g++, a = c);   d.push(1 < a.length ? e[a] :ax);
> for (b = 0; b < d.length; b++) d[b] = String.fromCharCode(d[b]);
> return d.join(""); }
>
> function de(b) {   var a, e = {}, d = b.split(""), c = f = d[0], g = [
> c ], h = o = 256;   for (b = 1; b < d.length; b++) a =
> d[b].charCodeAt(0), a = h > a ? d[b] :e[a] ? e[a] :f + c,
> g.push(a), c = a.charAt(0), e[o] = f + c, o++, f = a;   return
> g.join(""); }

Please note: These functions are for strings only.
Source: https://gist.github.com/JavaScript-Packer/bbf68a4dc0e1fd102221